# How to get Tridion item ID after created using Core Service

Tags: tridion

I am creating a new item using the Core Service in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599647/create-an-item-in-tridion-2011-using-core-service).  However, the URI of the newly created item is tcm:0-0-0 instead of the actual TCM URI.  the Title property is correct (and not New Component) but the WebDav path returns 'New Component' while .

What is the best way to get the URI of my newly created item?

```
client.Create(newComponent, null);
string newItemUri = newComponent.Id; // returns tcm:0-0-0
string webDavUrl = newComponent.LocationInfo.WebDavUrl;  // returns New%20Component
string title = newComponent.Title;  // correct
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second parameter of Create method are ReadOptions. They are used to specify how the item will be read back. In your example you have it set to null, meaning you will not read it back. What you should do is set ReadOptions and assign item read back to a variable, like this:

```
newComponent = (ComponentData) client.Create(newComponent, new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it uses the .Create method and I do not need to create an extra object to hold my saved data.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Ryan's code at http://blog.building-blocks.com/uploading-images-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011. He uses client.Save to get the saved Component, from which he's able to access the ID.