# How to create component in SDL Tridion 2011 using core service?

Tags: tridion

I want to create a component using core service in SDL Tridion 2011 using core service.
Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599647/create-an-item-in-tridion-2011-using-core-service

Comment: Hi Aquarius24 - Thanks for making your first Tridion related post on SO - Please consider committing to the Tridion Proposal on Area 51 also: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Ryan's excellent article on Creating items with Core Service http://blog.building-blocks.com/uploading-images-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011 or http://blog.building-blocks.com/creating-custom-pages-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011